# How can I get the count of hash keys that match an array in MongoDB?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I am using mongoid for rails (latest version).

I have a collection full of documents, each with a property that is a hash.

I want to do a query that will determine how many elements of a given array are hash keys in the array in a single document.

Something like:

```
@count = Product.where('id':'343434343').vendors_in_array('Walmart','Kmart').count()
```

Is this possible or do I need to pull back the entire document and figure it out in RoR?

Comment: There isn't an easy way to get the keys of the document rather than the values .. you would have to use Map/Reduce or some JS manipulation.  The faster approach would be to figure out your match counts in Ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will handle this in some other way because it doesn't seem to be the best approach.